# Swing vs Web app (HTML) for a project

Tags: java, html, swing, web-applications

We are currently about to embark on a new project and is deciding which technology to use, and I have been asked why HTML should be picked over Swing.

While my scope and experience of Swing is extremely limited I have come up with some of the following points which are more or less roughly mentioned. There is only one swing advantage mentioned at the moment and any more points regarding both webapps and swing advantages that could be added would be appreciated.

It would also be great if anyone can verify if the points I mentioned are correct, and if not how it should be corrected, along with mentioning any more points that can be added.

WEBAPP Advantages

1. Html is semantically structured
2. The presentation layer can be seperated when using HTML (using
   CSS). (As far as I have seen in Swing things like JFrame.setSize and
   such are embedded into the code and thus not seperated in any way)
3. Swing only runs on desktops AFAIK while an HTML webapp can run on
   any platform additionally there are various frameworks which will
   allow to create a webapp into an executable file such as APPJS if
   needed
4. There are likely to be more webapp (HTML) based developers than developers
   who know swing when it will come to future maintenance
5. There are a plethora of frameworks (JS mainly) and more support
   for webapps rather than Swing applications
6. Additionally if the application is based on a server client
   architecture the web application only needs to be deployed in one
   server
7. Swing applications require java to be installed on the client
   computer

SWING ADVANTAGES

1. Swing applications would be able to be programmed to be used
   offline with much less development than having this feature
   developed for webapps

Please note that these are just some points I came up with and the purpose of the question is to add in some more points to see which technology we might go for in our application rather than which technology is superior.

Regards,
Milinda

Comment: I believe that yours is a good question but one which invites debate and thus may not be the best type of question for this site.

Comment: Add [*Java Web Start*](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to _Swing Advantages_. The two approaches are sufficiently complementary to consider advocating both.